# Heroku-Connect with Postgres and Salesforce : The new rows are not synchronized

Tags: postgresql, salesforce, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

I'm trying to use Heroku Connect to integrate a Postgres database with Salesforce.
The goal is to add more data from DB to Salesforce.
After connecting I can see updates from Salesforce in Postgres.
I can update existing posts in Postgres and see them in Salesforce.
I can create new records in tables like Leeds, Accounts and Contacts and see all the updates in Salesforce.

The problem with the Opportunity table I manage to update existing records from Postgres, but can not create new records to synchronize with Salesforce.
I.e. produces but updates does not go to Salesforce.
The error obtained is:

```
{"op": "INSERT", "src": "SFDC", "msg": "We can't save this record because the \u201cOpportunity - Owner Assignment\u201d process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: Owner ID: owner cannot be blank. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1878853328-1317082 (142283924)k up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1878853328-1317082 (142283924)"}
```

I.e. error tells me that ownerid is blank. But this field is not empty because I give the correct values of ownerid.

```
INSERT INTO salesforce.opportunity ( name , closedate, stagename, createdbyid, ownerid )
Values('zzzz' ,'2021-12-31','New', '0051t000002VZvKAAW','0051t000002VZvKAAW' )
```

[image]

In Heroku connect this like that:
[image]
What could be a problem ??

Answer (score 0):

From the error reported it appears you have a flow configured on the opportunity object.  Check the flow logic to see what downstream updates are occurring that could produce this error, or disable the flow temporarily to verify your insert works as expected.